# How to monitor network connections made from a Adobe PDF file?

Tags: adobe, connection, monitoring, network-protocols, adobe-reader

I have a PDF file that fetches data from a server location. It prompts me before connecting and fetching data - how can I see what data its sending and retrieving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for this. You can monitor all data which passes your network device with wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a network debugging tool.  My favourite is [Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: Nice, fiddler is also a standalone application? I only know it as an IE plugin...

Comment: Yup fiddler is standalone and can debug https when needed.  Wireshark is good too though